# How to remove an item from owl-carousel 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

How can I remove an item from an owl carousel gallery?

Here's my html markup:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <img src="/assets/storage/gallery/1.jpg"></div>
    <img src="/assets/storage/gallery/2.jpg"></div>
    <img src="/assets/storage/gallery/3.jpg"></div>
    <img src="/assets/storage/gallery/4.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

And here's my JavaScript:

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  margin: 10,
  rtl: true,
  autoHeight: true,
  lazyLoad: true
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

according to [Owl Carousel Documentation](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-events.html) you can remove an index as following, however Owl Carousel 2 is in beta version right now, make sure to check docs in future for better ways (if they ever implement):

```
var indexToRemove = 2;
$(".owl-carousel").trigger('remove.owl.carousel', [indexToRemove]).trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
```

according to a comment, if it didn't work for you try the following:

```
var owlCarousel = jQuery(".owl-carousel").data('owlCarousel');
owlCarousel.removeItem(1);
```

Comment: This is not working. It seems that remove is conflicting with jquery remove, and will thus delete the entire carousel.

Comment: oh friend, thanyou, you save my time 

Answer (score 3):

I think this is version dependent

When I use below code

```
var indexToRemove = 2;
$(".owl-carousel").trigger('remove.owl.carousel', [indexToRemove]).trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
```

It's remove my carousel not particular slide.

Below code is worked for me.

```
var owlCarousel = jQuery(".owl-carousel").data('owlCarousel');
owlCarousel.removeItem(1);
```

I am using OwlCarousel v1.31

Answer (score 2):

You can use an owl carousel function call as below.

```
var indexToRemove = 2;
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel('remove', indexToRemove).owlCarousel('update');
```

Comment: How do you get the index of the item to be removed?