# Owl carousel hide second item while sliding to third item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I have used `URLhashListener` event to create horizontal page sliding.

Slide should be scroll direct to **Page 3**, when we click on **Page 3** button from **Page 1**. Now it is sliding over through Page 2.

How can I hide the second page when I go to **Page 3** from **Page 1**.

See my code:

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  autoplay: false,
  loop: false,
  nav: false,
  dots: false,
  center: true,
  mouseDrag: false,
  touchDrag: false,
  autoHeight: true,
  margin: 10,
  smartSpeed: 500,
  URLhashListener: true,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  startPosition: 'URLHash'
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.page {
  height: 10rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 200px;
}

.one {
  background: #bec4bd;
}

.two {
  background: green;
}

.three {
  background: #41253c;
}

.linkA {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.linkB {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="page one" data-hash="page1">
    Button at the bottom!
    <a href="#page2" class="linkA">Page 2</a>
    <a href="#page3" class="linkB">Page 3</a>
  </div>

  <div class="page two" data-hash="page2">
    Button at the bottom!
    <a href="#page1" class="linkA">Page 1</a>
    <a href="#page3" class="linkB">Page 3</a>
  </div>

  <div class="page three" data-hash="page3" style="color:#fff;">
    Button at the bottom!
    <a href="#page2" class="linkA">Page 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I doubt you can do that, unless you write a method to handle click event to suffice your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to remove the item by:

1. Adding `onclick="hidePage2();"` in the button in page 1 that goes to page 3
2. Adding the `hidePage2()` function (See below).

However, the page 2 gets deleted after removing (duh) but when trying to restore it with an "append" function or similar it get buggy. Nevertheless, here you have what I humbly came up with:

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  autoplay: false,
  loop: false,
  nav: false,
  dots: false,
  center: true,
  mouseDrag: false,
  touchDrag: false,
  autoHeight: true,
  margin: 10,
  smartSpeed: 500,
  URLhashListener: true,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  startPosition: 'URLHash'
});

function hidePage2(){
// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39543557/13023528

var indexToRemove = 1;
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel('remove', indexToRemove).owlCarousel('update');
}
```

```css
.owl-carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.page {
  height: 10rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 200px;
}

.one {
  background: #bec4bd;
}

.two {
  background: green;
}

.three {
  background: #41253c;
}

.linkA {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.linkB {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div id="owlCarousel" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="page one" data-hash="page1">
    Button at the bottom!
    <a href="#page2" class="linkA">Page 2</a>
    <a href="#page3" onclick="hidePage2();" class="linkB">Page 3</a>
  </div>

  <div class="page two" data-hash="page2">
    Button at the bottom!
    <a href="#page1" class="linkA">Page 1</a>
    <a href="#page3" class="linkB">Page 3</a>
  </div>

  <div class="page three" data-hash="page3" style="color:#fff;">
    Button at the bottom!
    <a href="#page2" class="linkA">Page 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: oops typo

Comment: Great try..! let me check more with your answer, and here Page 3 preventing click on Page 2 button.

Comment: The button doesn't work anymore because the HTML is deleted. If you try disabling visibility (either hidden or display: none) the page2 is in fact hidden BUT the carousel still shows a blank space, thus the removal. You could try appending the deleted HTML dynamically with JQuery, for example.